# Finding induced current (Faraday's and Lenzs law)

Tags: electromagnetism

This question was asked in JEE Mains and I am getting the answer as 2nd option by change in flux wrt time by differentiation. [image: the question] Please tell me if I am right and provide a solution

Comment: (1) The question that you quote is not well-worded. 'Concentric' should be 'co-axial' and the outer coil needs to have the ends of the wire of the coil connected together; describing the coil as 'conducting' doesn't guarantee that there is a current. (2) I agree with your answer; not only have you found /, but you have also applied Lenz's law. (3) This site doesn't provide solutions to homework-type questions; but it may sometimes consider conceptual issues that arise from such questions.

Comment: @VikasBalani On the other hand, SE does not allow homework-like questions. Although I know that JEE is not homework, but please show your _attempts_ along with the questions you post next time.

Comment: @PhilipWood Your comment (1) is worthless.  There's nothing wrong with the wording of the question.

Comment: @garyp. "worthless" is too strong a word to use. I appreciate that your view is different from mine, but this can be stated less offensively.

Comment: @PhilipWood Thank you for looking into the question. NTA (the agency that conducts this exam ) claims the answer to be 3 which is obviously incorrect .My 5 marks were at stake hence I had to challenge the question on their portal by paying a fee. I thought that physics stack exchange would be the best place to verify my answer (so I don't end up paying fee for a wrong question); and it is@KV18 provided me with a decent solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll have a try. Assuming $\alpha >0$,

$$I(t) = kte^{-\alpha t}$$

EMF induced in the loop will be proportional to the time derivative of the current - from $\epsilon = -\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ where $\phi$ is the magnetic flux through the loop due to the field from the solenoid.

Taking the time derivative of the current $I$, we get $(-\alpha kt + k)e^{-\alpha t}$. We multiply this by negative one and we can rewrite this into $ke^{-\alpha t}(\alpha t -1)$.
Remember that the induced EMF, and hence the *induced* current obeys this form (i.e. *induced* current is of the form of $I'(t)$. I have not included the $\mu_0$ constant because it is redundant and does not help to understand the curve in anyway).

Now, if you check at $t=0$, the induced current value $I^{'}(0) <0$.

So definitely the answer is **(2)**.

If you want to check this further, you can do that by setting $I^{'}(t)=0$, you would find the induced current to be zero at $t=1/\alpha$.

Unless you want to measure the peak of the *induced* current value: you would have to take the time derivative of the current first and then set the value to zero. That is actually the *second* derivative of $I(t)$. That would be at $t=2/\alpha$.

Comment: You're right`: the max rate of change of current is at $t=2/ \alpha.$

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was my first time posting a question on SE . I will definitely involve my attempts along with the question from next time.

Comment: @VikasBalani It is OK. I saw the jee key from allens, it said that the solution to this was something else. But I guess they got it wrong !